# Gnuplot lines overlap with tics

Tags: gnuplot, lines, overlap

How can I avoid that my lines of the plot overlap with the tics, I want to have them in front and the plots in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option to the `tics` command which does exactly that:

```
set tics front
```